# ASP.NET Request time out calling an async webmethod in ASMX from jquery

Tags: c#, vb.net, async-await, asmx, webmethod

I can't figure this out in days. I have tried everything. I have to change my cloud storage so I'm trying to refactor. First of all, I'm using MinIO in an intermediate class to connect the storage.

S3ObjectStorage.cs

```
public class S3ObjectStorage
{
    private MinioClient _client;
    private string _bucketName;

    public S3ObjectStorage(string key, string secret, string region, string httpsEndPoint, string bucketName) {
        _client = new MinioClient(httpsEndPoint, key, secret, region).WithSSL();
        _bucketName = bucketName;
    }

    public async Task<string> ListFilesAsync(string path)
    {
        return await ListObjects(path, false);
    }

    private async Task<string> ListObjects(string path, bool isDir) {
        var files = await _client.ListObjectsAsync(_bucketName, path)
            .Where<Item>(f => (isDir) ? (f.Key.EndsWith("/") && f.IsDir) : !f.Key.EndsWith("/"))
            .ToList();
        return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(files);
    }
}
```

TestPage.aspx.vb (runs properly)

```
Public Class TestPage
    Inherits Page

    Protected Async Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        cs = New S3ObjectStorage(CS_KEY, CS_SECRET, CS_REGION, HTTPS_ENDPOINT, BUCKET_NAME)
    End Sub

    Private Async Function List(path As String) As Task
        Dim resultFiles As String = Await cs.ListFilesAsync(path)
        Dim files = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(resultFiles)
        Me.rptFiles.DataSource = files
        Me.rptFiles.DataBind()
    End Function

End Class
```

Later I will try to use another technology, but for now, I need to use a webmethod in an ASMX to modify the code as little as possible. With the other cloud storage, all methods were synchronous, but MinIO doesn't.

index.aspx

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function listFiles() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", dataType: 'json', async: true,  
        url: '/WS/WSFileManager.asmx/ListFiles',
    ...);
```

WSFileManager.asmx.vb (trying 2 ways)

```
    <WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)>
    <ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)>
    Public Async Function ListFiles(signature As String, requestCode As String, previousDeleted As String) As Threading.Tasks.Task(Of String)

    'First way
    Dim minioClient As New MinioClient(GlobalConstants.S3_HTTPS_ENDPOINT,
                                           GlobalConstants.S3_KEY,
                                           GlobalConstants.S3_KEY,
                                           GlobalConstants.S3_REGION)
    minioClient.WithSSL()
    Dim files As New List(Of DataModel.Item)
    Dim observable As IObservable(Of DataModel.Item) = minioClient.ListObjectsAsync(GlobalConstants.S3_BUCKET_NAME, pathApp, False)
    Dim suscription As IDisposable = observable.Subscribe(
        Sub(item)
            files.Add(item)
        End Sub)
    suscription.Dispose()
    'files.Count always is 0
    
    'Second way
    Dim s3Storage As New S3ObjectStorage(GlobalConstants.S3_KEY, GlobalConstants.S3_SECRET,
                                        GlobalConstants.S3_REGION, GlobalConstants.S3_HTTPS_ENDPOINT,
                                        GlobalConstants.S3_BUCKET_NAME)
    Dim resultFiles As String = Await s3Storage.ListFilesAsync(pathApp)
'**Never reach this line**
....
```

My current cloud storage ends next January 31st, so I need the new one runs as soon as possible.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Timeout in your case probably means the connection never completed. First I would check the Event Viewer on the server to see if there are any error messages associated with your application. Then I would use a sniffer like wireshark to compare the working and non working connection. You are using TLS so make sure in the sniffer that TLS 1.2 or TLS 1.3 is being used.  Other versions of TLS are obsolete.  With TLS the server sends a certificate block (can see with sniffer) with names of certificate that can be used for encryption and then client looks up in stores the names of the certificates.

Comment: Thanks. However, when I call ListFilesAsync from TestPage it returns a result almost immediately.
And the same ASMX, using the other cloud, nevers returns a timeout.

```Dim resDC As GetDirectoryContentResponse = cs.GetDirectoryContent(CSAccessKeyId, ZuluTime, GenerateAppStorageSignature("GetDirectoryContent", ZuluTime), pathApp, "", "", "", "File")
If resDC.Error IsNot Nothing Then
    Return $"{{""error"":""Error listing files.<br />{resDC.Error.ErrorCode } {resDC.Error.Description}""}}"
End If
```

Comment: Does the other cloud always work?  You said never returns timeout.  Not sure what this means.  Does it mean never fails or just when it fails no error is returned.  When a connection fails sometimes you will get an error and sometimes it fails silently.

Comment: I mean I've get errors before but I'd never get a timeout with the other cloud using this same ASMX. I just changed the call to method and added "async" in function definition.

Comment: An Async method must get a EOM (end of message or equivalent) to know when all the data is received.  A connection must complete before you get a response.  A connection that doesn't complete never gets a response.  So in one case your connection is completing and returning a response.  You other case your connection is not completing which is what I said in my previous message.  So it looks like you connection is not completing and the Async is waiting for an EOM.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll try to check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was very very simple!

I have returned to putting the method in ASMX as synchronous

WSFileManager.asmx.vb

```
<WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)>
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)>
Public Function ListFiles(signature As String, requestCode As String, previousDeleted As String) As String

    Dim task = Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(Async Function() Await s3Storage.ListFiles(pathApp))
    task.Wait()
    Dim lFiles = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of DataModel.Item))(task.Result)
...
End Function
```

And in frontend, I've taken the opportunity to also stop using jQuery
index.aspx

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function listFiles() {
    const fetchOptions = {
        method: 'POST', headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'},
        body: JSON.stringify({ /* parameters */ })
    };
    const result = fetch('/WS/WSFileManager.asmx/ListFiles', fetchOptions)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
        .then(data => console.log(JSON.parse(data.d).legth+' files')));
...
```